# Strava V3 api upload gpx file php

Tags: php, api

i'm trying to upload a gpx file using strava api. I've already got the access token and i'm using this script :

```
$actual_file= realpath('/.../../myfile.gpx');

$url="https://www.strava.com/api/v3/uploads";

$postfields = array(
    "activity_type" => "ride",
    "data_type" => "gpx",
    "file" => '@' . $actual_file . ";type=application/xml"
);

$headers = array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $token);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

$response = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $response;
```

but  the response i get from strava is `{"message":"Bad Request","errors":[{"resource":"Upload","field":"file","code":"not a file"}]}`

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you should use `"file" => curl_file_create($actual_file)` for the file param. Also those params are out of date (check out [the new doc](https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Uploads-createUpload)).

I hope this will help someone. I discovered it while look through this [PHP wrapper for Strava's API](https://github.com/basvandorst/StravaPHP/blob/master/src/Strava/API/Service/REST.php)